# Sending input to GPIOC

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to send input to the pressing button (GPIOC 1<<13)
however I get an error that my statement is incorrect.
that's what I tried to run:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(GPIOC->IDR & (1<<13)), (uint8_t*)"Hello World\r\n", 16, 100); // Prints to the debugger's UART "Hello World"
```

and I keep getting "expected statement before ‘)’ token"

any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put an extra `)` after `(1 << 13)`, correct line would be:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(GPIOC->IDR & (1<<13), (uint8_t*)"Hello World\r\n", 16, 100);
```

Comment: but I have another Issue, it will not print to the button, and compile with error Description Resource Path Location Type
passing argument 1 of 'HAL_UART_Transmit' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] main.c /Hello_World/Core/Src line 108 C/C++ Problem

Comment: The parentheses error was just a minor issue. But your use of `HAL_UART_Transmit` still has a  bigger problem. Open a new question.